# If nick isin text file line x

Tags: irc, mirc

I'm having an issue with my current code.

```
on *:TEXT:*text*:#:{ 
  if ($nick isin $read(test.txt, 1)) {
    msg $chan working.
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is if the nick "User1" is in test.txt, and "User12" types text, It will detect it as User1 was in test.txt! How can I make it so "User12" will not say working if "User1" is on line 1.

Comment: Would using iswm instead of isin fix this?

Comment: what is in the first line of test.txt? only one nick or a lot of things? nick can be in other lines of test.txt? by the way, you must be very specific in your questions... "if the nick "User1" is in test.txt"... "It will detect it as User1 was in test.txt!"

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this isn't logical. Could you please publish the first line on `test.txt` ?

Comment: @OrelEraki  The first line of text.txt is "User12", the nick triggering the command is "User1"

Comment: what else has in test.txt? just the first line which contains "User12"?

Comment: @Sirius_Black yes... just that.

Comment: You got confused which make us confused, User12 is in text line, and User1 wrote `test`, which is completely opposite. Anyway i answered you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that `User1` contains in the first line `User12` and you're searching by `isin`.

You can use regex `$+(\b,$nick,\b)` with **\b** word boundary for for making sure there is not text before or after the searched *$nick*

```
on *:TEXT:*text*:#:{ 
  var %line = $read(test.txt, 1)
  if ($regex(%line, $+(\b,$nick,\b))) {
    msg $chan working.
  }
}
```

Comment: are you programming in PHP too? using ";" after setting a variable value... jk

Comment: up for the regex answer

Comment: Coming from  programming in .NET all day took its toll on me.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make it works, is using identifier $istok...

```
on *:TEXT:*text*:#:{ 
if ($istok($nick,$read(test.txt,1),32)) {
msg $chan working.
}
}
```

Since it will only search for a specific token at the specific string... $istok identifier will do the same match as **\b****\b** Regex Boundary

Comment: Up for another solution, specially non regex.

Comment: What is the ",32" for?

Comment: mIRC Help File:
$istok(text,token,C)

Returns $true if token exists, otherwise returns $false.

"32" stands for ASCII code for space character, which was used as delimiter character

Comment: have you changed what is in test.txt just for a bit? even insivible characters count...

Comment: It apparently never worked, I was unable to test it, Other user's solution works.

Comment: so you probably gave insufficient information, since i tested it and worked, the way you asked, by the way, any other information that its not like "User1" **only** in the first line of test.txt, will not work